# 275309 while installing mavenmate into the sublime

Tags: salesforce, sublimetext3

I am new to the `SalesForce` and `MavenMate` installation to the `Sublime text`. Even I am new to the `Sublime Text`. I am following the link https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/sublime-text-3-mavensmate-for-salesforce-development/ to install the mavensmate into sublime and I encountered with the below error:

I am not sure why its giving me the 275309 error. Could any one please give any help?

I only want the correct steps to install mavensmate into sublime.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Oh I got the solution of this issue. As soon as you enter the below code show console and enter then you need to goto the `Preferences > Package Control`，input “install”, then select “`Package Control: Install Package`” menu. Done !!. You are OK to go.

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'df21e130d211cfc94d9b0905775a7c0f' + '1e3d39e33b79698005270310898eea76'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```